# ASP.NET Core 2:2 error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'. on login process

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am struggling with this error which is highlighting on:
`var account = db.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Username.Equals(username));`.
The error message I am getting is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

My data type is not `int`. I am wondering where the `Int32` part is coming from. Below is my code:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("process")]
public IActionResult Process(string username, string password)
{
    var account = processLogn(username, password);
    if (account != null)
    {
        securityManager.SignIn(this.HttpContext, account);
        return RedirectToAction("index","dashboard", new { area = "admin" });
        //return View("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.error = "Invalis Account";
        return View("Index");
    }
}

private Account processLogn(string username, string password)
{
    var account = db.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Username.Equals(username));
    if (account != null)
    {
        if (BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(password, account.Password))
        {
            return account;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is my class:

```cs
[Table("Account")]
public class Account {
    public Account()
    {
        RoleAccounts = new HashSet<RoleAccount>();
    }
    
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RoleAccount> RoleAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

Table description:

```
Username varchar(250) Checked
```

Comment: Can you provide the class definition for `Account` and the underlying table definition for `Accounts`? It seems as if your table is defined as `Username` being a numeric type.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be that `Id` column in the database is of type `int` and in your `Account` class it has a type `string`.